# What is wrong with this code that generates an error?

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know what is wrong with this code, could someone please spot the mistake?.  Igives me the error:

> object does not support this property or method.

```
Sub copyrow2()

Dim Lastro As Integer
Dim nLastro As Integer
Dim Rng As Range

nLastro = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
Lastro = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Lastro < nLastro Then

With oSht = ActiveSheet
Set Rng = oSht.Range("J" & Lastro & ":" & "k" & nLastro)
      Rng.Copy
      oSht.Range("H" & Lastro).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
End With

End If
```

Comment: You can put a break in the beginning of your code and step through until you get the error.

Comment: You've asked 9 questions, but not accepted any answers... why not?

Comment: One may request an asker to accept answers (if the asker is new) but you may not force him to do it :) REF: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers

Comment: @SiddharthRout, that seems pretty obvious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of problems with the code

1. Please use `Option Explicit`. That will force you to declare variables. For example `oSht` is undeclared.
2. When working with rows, never declare tham as `Integers`. There is a huge possibility that you may get an error in xl2007+. Declare them as `Long`
3. Avoid the use of `ActiveSheet/Select` etc. [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)
4. Fully qualify `Rows.Count`. When working with several excel files in compatibility mode, it could result in an error if you don't fully qualify them.

Is this what you are trying?

**Code: (untested)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyrow2()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim Lastro As Long, nLastro As Long
    Dim Rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With oSht
        nLastro = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
        Lastro = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        If Lastro < nLastro Then
            Set Rng = .Range("J" & Lastro & ":" & "k" & nLastro)
            Rng.Copy .Range("H" & Lastro)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: We should make a mandatory "Use Option Explicit" alert for all questions posted here...